# How do I pass data to a button click event in Swift IOS?

Tags: ios, swift

In my project, there is a UITableView which contains UICollectionViews in each row. Each UICollectionView contains a UIButton. I implemented those by using a tutorial here:

https://ashfurrow.com/blog/putting-a-uicollectionview-in-a-uitableviewcell-in-swift/

The problem is, I need to add an action to button click. The usual IBAction click works, but I can't pass any data except an integer (tag) to it.

The question is, how do I pass some data to my button click action?

Comment: Can you post some code that you have tried.

Comment: "Each UICollectionView contains a UIButton". How can UIcollectionView Contains a UIButton. do you mean inside a UICollectionViewCell ?
What kind of data you want to pass to the UIButton?

Comment: What do you mean by "pass data to it"? You want to identify which button?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UIButton in UICollectionViewCell

UICollectionViewCell in UICollectionView

UICollectionView in UITableViewCell

UITableViewCell in UITableView

UITableView in UIViewController/UITableViewController

so your button outlet must be on collectionviewcell class and your button's action must be in uicollectionviewcell, and you can pass data from your uicollectionviewcell to UITableViewCell with delegate (uicollectionviewcell-delegate), and UITableViewCell to UIViewController/UITableViewController with another delegate.